# How to pass Null in SOAP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, soap, null

I have the following method signature in my WCF web service:

```
public CreateItemResult CreateAgent(int tenantId, string loginName, int timeZoneId)
```

How can I pass Null value for `timeZoneId` in my SOAP? I've tried to pass the following in my SOAP request but it did not work:

```
<timeZoneId i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

Must I change `int timeZoneId` to be `int? timeZoneId` in my WCF web service in order to pass Null values to it?  Is there any other way?
Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried to pass the `null` `timeZoneId`?  Maybe check the schema that's generated for your service.  If the `minOccurs` is 0 then you should be able to omit the element altogether.  If you don't see it, `minOccurs` defaults to one.  See if making the `timeZoneId` nullable changes the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want to pass null you need to make your `timeZoneId` in your operation contract nullable (`int?`). Otherwise `timeZoneId` element is considered as not nillable in XSD schema.